# My app can't read its self-made HTML files on internal storage

Tags: android, html, file, storage

As the question's title says, I have an app that generates HTML files on Android internal storage.

Here's how I did it:

Reading the file

```
        if (thereIsSomethingToShow)
        {
            File dir = getDir("MyApp", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            File newfile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Ref+"-"+Name+".html");
            mWebview.loadUrl("file:/"+dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+Ref+"-"+Name+".html"); //("file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/*+"//MyApp//MySheets//"*/+"//"+Ref+"-"+Name+".html");
            setContentView(mWebview);
        }
```

Writing the file (before code above in my class)

```
File root = getDir("MyApp", MODE_WORLD_READABLE); //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Ref+"-"+Name+".html"); //new File(root, Ref+"-"+Name+".html");
f.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "ISO-8859-1"));
bw.write(rs.getFullCode());
bw.close();
```

The HTML file is generated well in the indicated location, but I can't read it, neither in my app's webView nor in my browser, unless I move the HTML file to External Storage using Root Explorer.

If I don't, both my browser and my webView will display "Webpage unavailable".
Note that if I use the values in comments, everything will be fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FOUND IT!
I was only missing a slash after "file:/" in the 5th line of my Reading code snippet. :)
It's supposed to be "file://" actually.

Comment: please add your finding as an answer and accept it